# What is Safari's "local storage"?

Tags: safari, filesystem

I see that Safari stores three things: Cache, Cookies, and "local storage."

I know what cache and cookies are, but what is "local storage"?

Semantically, cache and cookies **are** local storage, but presumably this is a third type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local storage [appears to be](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionSettings/ExtensionSettings.html) the holding area for [HTML 5 Client Side storage](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/) which can be used by modern web apps to store data locally for various purposes.